# Connecting a Windows 7 client to local Mac OS X server

Tags: windows-7

I was previously able to connect a Windows 7 client to the local Mac OS X server without any issues. Then due to internet connection issues, the router had to be reset.

Since then the Windows 7 client has not been able to properly connect to the locacl Mac OS X server.

Within Windows Explorer and the Network and Sharing Center, the server shows up in the Network lists, but does not show any folders or files when I click to connect. There are no error messages appearing either.

Any ideas what I can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 and later clients no longer support the Windows NT 4.0 PDC technology provided in Mac OS X Server v10.6 and earlier.

see: http://support.apple.com/kb/ts3235